# English grammar "here the ... "

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

I have to apologize for this question but I am having some issues with someone saying that you can use the phrase

> Here the bus can come

That sounds really awkward to my ears and I feel like it's wrong. In the past I was a lot better at grammar but I've sadly let those skills slip and I can't explain why this might be incorrect.

Here is the actual sentence being discussed:

The bus comes => Here comes the bus. How can I meet the sentence "the bus can come here"; is it OK to say "Here the bus can come"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! What do you think was the intended meaning of the sentence? "This is a piece of territory where a bus can arrive"?

Comment: hi @CowperKettle I updated the question with the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

*Here comes the bus* is **not** equivalent to *The bus comes*; it is an idiom which means, approximately, "The bus is in sight and about to arrive".

(There's a parallel idiom, *There goes the bus*, which means, approximately, "The bus is still in sight but has just departed".)

*The bus can come here* means "It is possible for the bus to come here", so it is not compatible with the *Here comes/goes* idiom.

It is possible to say *Here the bus can come* grammatically. But this is not an ordinary use; it 'fronts' the adverb *here* in order to contrast it with other locations. For instance:

> When they got the new long buses King Street was too narrow for the bus to make the turn. Here, the bus **can** come, and that's why the moved the bus stop here.

Comment: I think you had a typo here: "The bus can **came** here means [...]" -> "The bus can **come** here means [...]"

Comment: Thank you very much for providing such a detailed answer.